# Functor operating on generics not accepted by find_if

Tags: c++

Let us consider the following section of code:

```
template <class T, class Comp>
Class MyClass { 

public:
   struct my_functor {
    public:
        my_functor(const T w) : wanted(w) {}
        bool operator()(const T t) {
            return customEquals(t,wanted);
        }
    private:
        T wanted;
   };


private:
   std::vector<T> container;
   bool customEquals(T a, T b) { ... }
};
```

When I further try to call

```
std::find_if(container.begin(),container.end(),v,my_functor(v));
```

Where v is input of type `T const&`, I get the following compilation error (g++,C++14):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find_if(std::vector<int>::iterator,std::vector<int>::iterator,const int&,MyClass<int,bool(*)(int,int)>::my_functor)
```

`T` is `int` in this particular example.

What seems to be the problem here?

PS: I have all the required headers included (algorithm,vector,functional,...), so the problem's not there.

Comment: The `,v` has nohing to do here. `find_if` only takes a range and a functor.

Comment: _"The functor works fine without templated T"_ I highly doubt that. If so, show this mythical code that compiles while passing both a value and a predicate to compare against.

Comment: @underscore_d It worked fine because when I was trying out the non-templated version, I made sure to exclude the v, but not in the templated version for some reason. My (very stupid) mistake, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What seems to be the problem here?

Not really sure why you have expected this code to work.

To start with, you need to check [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) overloads. There are no overloads which accept both value to find and custom predicate, only predicate is accepted.

Then, if you use `my_functor`, the code should look like this:

```
std::find_if(std::cbegin(container), std::cend(container),
    MyClass<T, Comp>::my_functor(v));
```

Where `T` and `Comp`are some types.

Comment: Rokyan Oh man, Thank you! I can't help myself but to facepalm at this mistake, I was first using the normal find and later transitioned to find_if without noticing that it doesn't take the v anymore. It's working now hehe.

Comment: @P.Lance no problem :)